# Can a purely declarative language cause runtime exceptions?

Tags: declarative-programming, formal-methods

Let us consider a purely declarative language such as SQL, XQuery, or a logic language like Prolog, or a purely functional language without variable mutability.

Considering that the interpreter or compiler for a such language is free of bugs and can check every type errors, could a program written in such language have a side effects which leads to an unwanted behaviour(s) or eventually a runtime error?

Comment: [Compilers cannot solve the Halting Problem.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/why-really-is-the-halting-problem-so-important)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "fail". You can certainly write SQL queries that produce errors or return zero rows.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, my question is maybe stupid...

Comment: @Niels You can design languages that always terminate and depending on how you define *success* it might even terminate successfully all the time. But such languages won't be able to solve every problem.

Comment: Define what you mean by "fail".

Comment: Would delivering a perfectly working dentist scheduling application when you were asked to build the flight control software for a 747 be considered "failing"?

Comment: To elaborate on @RobertHarvey's comment: a common problem would be non-termination, a program that loops forever. You can hang the computer with Prolog :)

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "unclear" if you do not quickly start to edit it and tell us what you mean by "fail".

Comment: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." --Donald Knuth

Comment: [`a:-a.`](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59408/903) (prolog infinite loop)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Consider, for example, running out of memory. Or, if the program is not 'pure', i/o errors. Or even stuff like division by 0.

Answer (score 2):

For a well-known, mainstream example (I presume), transforms written in XSLT 1.0 (without using any extension functions) are [strongly normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting)#Normalization_properties) and (thus) always terminate. XSLT certainly falls in the "*fairly*" declarative (*) language category, and also only knows about / only allows immutable variables.

[No risk of infinite loops](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Processing-Model) for the finite inputs you feed it.

But then, of course, it isn't Turing-complete (without the use of extensions), and one can certainly write transforms which output nothing really useful (or something one didn't quite expect).

Still, I'm not sure if it'd be fair to call such possibilities "failures" *because* of the language's semantic, strictly speaking.

'HTH,

(* and verbose, but that's another topic)